# Background Color Disappears On Desktop

Tags: html, css

I have a Background color added to an image that sits to the left of another div with content. The background color shows up as it should when viewed on mobile, however when viewed on desktop the color disappears. All styles have to be done inline as I do not have access to the main css.

```html
<article class="page__group " style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
<div class="content-block__inner; position: relative;">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="icon-title__image" style="padding: 0% 0%; background-color: #22a9e0;"><img src="/media/5425/facecovering-transparent-150x150.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="icon-title__blurb color--tertiary-dark" style="font-size: 1.125em; line-height: 1.45; background-color: #e8e8e8; float: right; padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong><br /><br />consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
```

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDuoB.png)

[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i70Lu.png)

Comment: I doubt you'll get any help with this without seeing other CSS.  Or at least live example to look at source code. But try adding  background-color: #22a9e0 !important ;

Comment: Do you use a CSS library? Also, you don't have to use inline style of you don't have access main CSS file. You can include another file and use same CSS rules to change the style.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, I don't have access to any CSS. nor can I upload another file. This is being done in umbraco, with very little access to anything other than what I have posted. I did try the !important; but that did not work.

Comment: I know I am not giving you all much to go off of. Was just hoping there might be something simple I was missing.